# Looking for a windows-based WebDAV enabled editor (for code)

Tags: windows, text-editing, webdav

I'm looking for a good editor for windows with built-in WebDAV support. I'm aware of Netdrive, Webdrive and Windows' built-in WebDAV client, but these don't work as well, because they need to emulate a true filesystem.

Has anyone came across this? I'm used to Coda on OS/X, so I'm hoping for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Similar discussion on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777586/looking-for-a-good-webdav-enabled-windows-editor). However, I don't think they came up with an answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yea you're right.. I wanted to try my luck here =)

Answer (score 1):

jEdit had (has?) a WebDAV plugin, but it's site has become a spamsite (webdav.us) and the current state is unknown to me.